# How to represent arbitrary function calls with a Django model

Tags: python, metaprogramming

So I'm working on a neat project that involves some meta-programming. What I'd like my application to do is allow users to record a "script" of actions, where each action corresponds strictly to a single function call on a well-defined Python library (let's call it lib_foo). Once the script is recorded, the application will automatically play it back by running the ordered list of function calls as a periodic task.

My question is: what is the best way to represent an arbitrary Python function call as a Django model? Need to take into account *args, **kwargs, class methods, etc and represent these as model fields. My naive approach is something like this:

```
class Klass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(choices=LIST_OF_CLASS_NAMES_IN_LIB_FOO)

class Function(models.Model):
    klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(choices=LIST_OF_FUNCTION_NAMES_IN_LIB_FOO)

class Arg(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    data_type = models.CharField(choices=LIST_OF_SIMPLE_JSON_TRANSLATABLE_DATA_TYPES)

class Kwargs(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)
    name = models.CharField()
    data_type = models.CharField(choices=LIST_OF_SIMPLE_JSON_TRANSLATABLE_DATA_TYPES)

class FunctionCall(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)
    periodicity = models.IntegerField() #amount of time in seconds between playbacks

class FunctionCallArg(models.Model):
    function_call = models.ForeignKey(FunctionCall, related_name="args")
    arg_def = models.ForeignKey(Arg)
    value = models.CharField() #again, stick to simple JSON-translatable values here

class FunctionCallKwarg(models.Model):
    function_call = models.ForeignKey(FunctionCall, related_name="kwargs")
    kwarg_def = models.ForeignKey(Kwarg)
    value = models.CharField() #as JSON
```

So...I think that seems like enough to record a list of tightly-constrained function calls for playback. I guess what I'd like to ask is:

- Am I forgetting anything fundamental?
- Am I re-inventing the wheel? (i.e. is there a decent lib for this already)
- Is this whole approach maybe just really stupid and naive? Maybe I'm approaching it completely wrong and I'd like you to tell me if you think that's the case.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you want to do, but maybe the [ast module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) could help you?